# After replacing starter no start

Tags: honda, starting, starter, odyssey

After replacing a bad starter, the engine will crank but stops mid crank every fifth turn of the crankshaft. It's a 2003 Honda Odyssey 6 cylinder.

Comment: It sounds like you've received a bad starter.

Comment: Have you validated your battery is in good shape and fully charged?

Comment: Why did you replace the starter? What was it doing/not doing that caused you to replace it?